# How to update all children in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm try on firebase update all child on one level of tree. For example something like this:

```
firebase.child("auctions").child().update({a: true});
```

and this give me back error, because child is empty. Are there any way how update all children of auctions?

Comment: for clear understand, i've got this structure `auctions->item1`->a->true` and item i've got more than one. Are there any way how make change for all `a`? Thank's

Answer (score 3):

You don't need that empty `.child()` invocation.

What `firebase.child("auctions").update({a: true});` is going to do is change
`/auctions/a/whatever` to `/auctions/a/true`.

If you really want to "update all child on one level of tree" then `.set` might work better since it will replace all the data at the endpoint with the object you give it. So if you ran 
`firebase.child("auctions").set({a: true});` then everything under `/auctions` will be replaced with `{a: true}`

If you didn't want to blast away everything under `/auctions` but instead you wanted to blast away everything under `auctions/a` you could do
`firebase.child("auctions/a").set(true);`

There are multiple ways to accomplish what you need. I'm just not 100% sure what you actually are in need of.

Comment: I wrote maybe not absolute clear structure of firebase. I've got this structure: `auctions > item1 > a = 5` and I would like set all {{a}} to 0 (for example).  Are there any way how I can write some like this: `firebase.child("auctions").child("*").update({a: 0});` Thank's

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop over all children at some point. Here's one simple way to do this:

```
firebase.child("auctions").on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref().update({a: true}); // or snapshot.ref if you're in SDK 3.0 or higher
});
```

Alternatively you can first collect all updates and then send them to Firebase as one (potentially big) update statement:

```
var updates = {};
firebase.child("auctions").on('value', function(snapshot) {
    updates["auctions/"+snapshot.key+"/a"] = true;
});
snapshot.ref().update(updates);  // or snapshot.ref if you're in SDK 3.0 or higher
```

Both snippets accomplish the same, but the latter send a single command so is more resilient in the case of network failure.

Comment: Hi, this I try to, but stil this is in bad level of JSON. I save original JSON before used to http://tmp2.aikidohostivar.cz/example/auctions-orig.json and after used is statue like: http://tmp2.aikidohostivar.cz/example/auctions-after-req.json
As you can see, I try change global attribute "name" and it is on bad level : (

Comment: in Firebase V3 .ref is no longer a function - just remove the () from the first example

Comment: How will you get the snapshot reference outside the callback function?